# Wordpress hook firing before post meta is being updated

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

```
function auto_assign_taxonomies($post_id) {

 if (get_post_type($post_id) == 'sales') {
     $terms1 = get_field("sales_product", $post_id, false);
     $terms2 = get_field("sales_product_2", $post_id, false);
     $terms3 = get_field("sales_product_3", $post_id, false);
     $terms4 = get_field("sales_product_4", $post_id, false);
     $terms5 = get_field("sales_product_5", $post_id, false);
     $terms6 = get_field("sales_product_6", $post_id, false);
     $terms7 = get_field("sales_product_7", $post_id, false);
     $terms8 = get_field("sales_product_8", $post_id, false);
     $arr = ["$terms1","$terms2","$terms3","$terms4","$terms5","$terms6","$terms7","$terms8"];
     
     
     wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $arr, 'product', false );
     
 }
}

add_action('save_post', 'auto_assign_taxonomies');
```

Hello, I´m trying to update a custom taxonomy  `product` from a custom post type  `sales`, using Advanced Custom Fields values, the function itself is working great and the data is being converted to a taxonomy, but the problem here is that the hook I´m using,  `save_post` seems to be giving me the meta value from before the post is saved, I´ve already tried the  `edit_post` hook as well but without success, if someone could please help me in this regard I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

You could query the $_POST data for the new values.

To do this, for each field use a snippet like this.

```
$field_obj = get_field_object( "fieldname", $post_id );
$field_key = $field_obj["key"];
$new_data = $_POST["acf"][$field_key];
$curr_data = get_field( "fieldname", $post_id );
```

Note: I'm not sure if this makes a difference (don't believe it should), however, I was doing this in a different hook, "acf/save_post".